# JavaScript: why for loop works differently with var & let

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to understand the reason but didn't found it yet. So asking here.

**The below prints i value fine when I use let i = 0**

```
for(let i=0; i < 5; i++){
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i) // 0 1 2 3 4
  }, 1000)
}
```

**The below prints i value 5 when I use var i = 0**

```
for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i) // 5 5 5 5 5
  }, 1000)
}
```

Please help me to understand **why** it works this way?.

Comment: I did take a look https://wesbos.com/for-of-es6 but it just says let is block-scoped.

Comment: this is literally why they introduced the `let` keyword in javascript. Just look at its description

Comment: Also relevant: [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. I am asking **why** and all other questions are **how to**?

Comment: They also explain the reason - `var` is scoped to the whole function, so you get one variable for every loop iteration. When the loop finishes, and the delayed functions execute, they all read the same value. `let` is scoped only to the block there is a separate value for each iteration.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29558498/) which directly addresses this.